# Does @ComponentScan need to be on the same class as @Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Why do `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration` always go hand in hand?
It seems like a class that has `@Configuration` always needs to be annotated with `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: A class with `@Configuration` isn't required to have `@ComponentScan` but often you have just 1 of those and that is also anntated with `@ComponentScan`. You could (in theory) also add `@ComponentScan` to regular components but as this is configuration that might be frowned upon.

Comment: What are the implications if they are on different files ?

Answer (score 0):

**Config class**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    
    @Bean
    public Animal animal()
    {
        return new Animal();
    }
}
```

**Application Class**

```
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        System.out.println(context.containsBeanDefinition("animal"));
        System.out.println(context.containsBeanDefinition("application"));
    }
```

**Output**

> true
> true

In above example , @Configuration not used on Application Class , so it is not mandatory to have @Configuration where @ComponentScan is used.